# Java UDP server-client showing square characters

Tags: java, udp, client

I used an example of a UDP server / client that i found here: http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/

The client sends a string to the server and the server changes the lowercase letters to uppercase.

The Server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
class UDPServer
{

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9876);
    byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
    byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];

    while(true) {   
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,     receiveData.length);
        serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);

        String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData());
        System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);
        InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();

        int port = receivePacket.getPort();
        String capitalizedSentence = sentence.toUpperCase();
        sendData = capitalizedSentence.getBytes();

        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
        serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
    }
}

}
```

The client:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
class UDPClient
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in,     "UTF-16"));

    DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
    InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
    byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
    byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];

    String sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
    sendData = sentence.getBytes();

    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 9876);
    clientSocket.send(sendPacket);

    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
    clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);

    String modifiedSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
    System.out.println("FROM SERVER:" + modifiedSentence);
    clientSocket.close();
}
}
```

The output when i write test in the client:

```
test
FROM SERVER:TEST□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□.....
```

Comment: If the solution below didn't work, how did you eventually solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Because you declared a packet size:

```
byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket receivePacket = 
   new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
```

The following code will return a string of length 1024:

```
String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData() );
```

You need to use receivePacket.getLength() to get the payload size, so change it to this:

```
String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getLength() );
```

That should do it!